# Parsing Form Url Encoded Request To Case Class

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a situation where I receive a request to my Play service as form url-encoded content. But the problem is that the field names in the request are different to my case class field names, so how do I create an instance of my case class easily? For example,

**Payload**

```
To="john"&From="amy"
```

**case class definition**

```
case class Payload(to : String, from : String)
```

This is not a form so I do not create `Form` and use `bindRequest` (even that I don't think will work).

If this was JSON payload then I could create my own Reads but this is url form encoded so is it possible to create my own equivalent "Reads" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite request not being submitted via web form you should still handle `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request using regular form processing mechanics. Try defining the following model and mapping

```
  case class Payload(to: String, from: String)

  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "To" -> nonEmptyText,
      "From" -> nonEmptyText
    )(Payload.apply)(Payload.unapply)
  )
```

Note how in the form mapping the field name case does not have to match the corresponding one in the model, for example, `To` vs `to`. What matters is the field order and the types. Now handle the request using regular `form.bindFromRequest`.